# Redirect на мобильную версию

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect, mobile

**Есть сайт: domen.ru
моб. версия: m.domen.ru**

Проблема заключается в следующем:
ссылка с сайта domen.ru на xxx.domen.ru 
всегда редиректом получается m.domen.ru
Как исправить ситуацию, чтобы можно было пройти по ссылке на xxx.domen.ru ?

**файл .htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
AddDefaultCharset Off
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
    php_flag register_globals off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
    php_flag register_globals off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domen\.ru$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domen.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://domen.ru/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domen.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам в действительности не нужно отлавливать столько устройств, чтобы покрыть большую часть мобильных устройств (вы же всё равно не адаптируете под каждое из них):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^m\.domen\.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://m.domen.ru/$1 [L,R,NE,QSA]
```