# Как исключить Redirect на мобильную версию для субдомена

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect

Есть основной сайт domen.ru, его мобильная версия на m.domen.ru и другой сайт на субдомене xxx.domen.ru. 
При обращении с моб. устройства к сайту domen.ru происходит редирект на мобильную версию m.domen.ru.

**Проблема:** Нельзя загрузить с мобильного устройства сайт xxx.domen.ru (не мобильная версия), т.к. сразу идет редирект на моб. версию m.domen.ru

**Файл .htaccess:**

```
      Options +FollowSymlinks
      AddDefaultCharset Off
```

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
    php_flag register_globals off
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
   php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
   php_flag register_globals off
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_dir.c>
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domen\.ru$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domen.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://domen.ru/ [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
   </IfModule>

   RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
   # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
   # Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 
   # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]
   # Now redirect to the mobile site
   RewriteRule ^ http://m.domen.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это дубликат вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578141/redirect-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e

Comment: вопрос не был решен, поэтому пришлось создать новый с более полной формулировкой.

Comment: @designer Пожалуйста, используйте ссылку [edit], расположенную под метками вопроса, для того, чтобы внести дополнения/уточнения в вопрос. Новый вопрос следует задавать в том случае, если у вас появилась новая проблема/задача.

Comment: @designer, сразу за строкой `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.` строку `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^xxx\.`

Answer (score 1):

Намой взгляд правильный вариант поставить опцию "показывать полную версию сайта", в настройках мобильного браузера. Точно не помню как она звучит. В яндекс браузере, есть опция "показать полную версию сайта".
Тогда, сам браузер будет отправлять user-agent "настольного" аналога и htaccess его не направит на m.domain.ru

Либо править .htaccess, закомментировать все строки после `</IfModule>`, до конца файла.

`#RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 
...`

и так далее. В дальнейшем, просто убрать комментирование.

Еще можно использовать эмуляцию мобильного браузера на PC, с помощью средств разработчика. Поищите, например "*мой_браузер* эмуляция мобильных устройств".

Comment: Skit, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Но, мы не можем всем пользователям сайта предлагать делать такие настройки в браузере. Мобильная версия нам нужна в любом случае, иначе пропадает смысл ее создания. Можно настроить исключение для xxx.domen.ru в .htaccess, чтобы с него не было редиректа на  m.domain.ru?

Comment: Конечно, это можно сделать! К сожалению, у меня мало опыта с этим, сходу не могу сказать.